# How to create a shortcut to existing annotation?

Tags: java, scala, annotations

In my code I am using following annotation several times:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = classOf[CustomColorRGBASerializer])
```

To keep my code short and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I would like to create a shortcut to this, something like:

```
class JsonSerializeARGB
  extends @JsonSerialize(using = classOf[CustomColorRGBASerializer])
```

which I could then use as a new `@JsonSerializeARGB` annotation

I can use annotation, but I do not know how to define them, therefore my attempt certainly looks naive and obviously incorrect, but I hope it bears the meaning through.

I have read [How do you define an @interface in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265773/how-do-you-define-an-interface-in-scala) and [How to create annotations and get them in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177010/how-to-create-annotations-and-get-them-in-scala), but they did not help me much, as I do not want to create a brand new annotation, rather "subclass" existing annotation. Can this be done?

If there is no Scala solution, can something like this be done in Java? (The [Jackson annotations](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html) I am working with are defined in Java anyway).

Comment: I don't think Jackson has support, but the concept you're looking for is called meta-annotation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a custom Jackson annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921812/create-a-custom-jackson-annotation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid there is [no way to subtype annotation with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java) (and Scala) language mechanisms. I think that the only solution is to make a Scala [macro with the annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310144/scala-type-aliases-for-annotations).

[Macro annotations](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) are available with [Macro Paradise plugin](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) for Scala compiler. Hopefully they 'll be included in Scala 2.13. To configure SBT for Macro Paradise you may want to follow [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767580/resolving-the-dependency-of-scala-macros-and-compiler-framework-in-sbt). There is also a [useful example](https://github.com/scalamacros/sbt-example-paradise) of project making use of macro paradise.

I believe that this can be done better (especially DefDef matching), but macro similar to this one should solve your problem:

```
import scala.reflect.macros._
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.language.experimental.macros

class JsonSerializeARGB extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro JsonSerializeARGBMacroImpl.impl
}

object JsonSerializeARGBMacroImpl extends JsonSerializeARGBMacro

class JsonSerializeARGBMacro {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
      import c.universe._

      def modifiedDef(d: DefDef) = {
        val (mods, name, tparams, paramss, tpt, body) = try {
          val q"$mods def $name[..$tparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $body" = d
          (mods, name, tparams, paramss, tpt, body)
        } catch {
          case _: MatchError => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Failed to match...")
        }

        //TODO there is a problem with modifiers
        c.Expr(q"""
          @JsonSerialize(using = classOf[CustomColorRGBASerializer])
          def $name[..$tparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $body
          """)
      }

      annottees.map(_.tree) match {
        case (d: DefDef) :: Nil => modifiedDef(d)
        case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Invalid annottee.")
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at Java, there is no reasonable way to do this. [Annotations cannot be extended in current Java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java), so the easiest approach fails. An other possiblity would be to use reflection to replace all occurrences of a `JsonSerializeARGB` with `JsonSerialize`, though this would only work at runtime, not at compile time. Yet the Java Reflection API only supports [reading annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html), not adding them.

So there are two theoretical approaches:

- Messing with the compiled byte code, but nobody can honestly want to do that.
- Modifying Jackson (or any other library that reads the annotations) to recognize your custom `JsonSerializeARGB` annotation.

I’m not familiar with Scala, so I do not know whether there are other options available there. But I doubt that Scala provides methods to add or extends annotation that Java doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a different approach. Jackson supports programattically defining serializers. So you can define your own annotation and then use reflection to find all classes with your annotation and add the serializer mapping.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null))
// use reflections to find all classes with Annotation the
for (classWithAnnotation <- classesWithAnnotation) {
  simpleModule.addSerializer(classWithAnnotation, new CustomColorRGBASerializer());
}
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example I tried to get what you wanted to do with fasterXML library:

#### 1. Create your own CustomSerializer

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<CustomDTO> {

@Override
public void serialize(CustomDTO value, JsonGenerator gen,
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeStringField("AccentColor", value.getAccentColor());
    gen.writeStringField("ButtonColor", value.getButtonColor());
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

}

#### 2. Create Annotation to use this CustomSerializer:

*As of Scala 2.11 this needs to be done in Java, as in Scala it is currently not possible to define annotations with runtime retention.*

```
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonAnnotationsInside;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
public @interface JsonSeriliazerCustom {}
```

#### 3. Use this on CustomDTO or your class as follows:

```
@JsonSeriliazerCustom
public class CustomDTO {

    private String buttonColor;
    private String accentColor;
    private String frontColor;

    public String getButtonColor() {
        return buttonColor;
    }

    public void setButtonColor(String buttonColor) {
        this.buttonColor = buttonColor;
    }

    public String getAccentColor() {
        return accentColor;
    }

    public void setAccentColor(String accentColor) {
        this.accentColor = accentColor;
    }

    public String getFrontColor() {
        return frontColor;
    }

    public void setFrontColor(String frontColor) {
        this.frontColor = frontColor;
    }


}
```

#### 4. Write your main method like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker;
import com.opera.oss.core.dto.CustomDTO;

public class TestJson {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CustomDTO responseDTO = new CustomDTO();
        responseDTO.setAccentColor("red");
        responseDTO.setButtonColor("blue");
        responseDTO.setFrontColor("yellow");
        System.out.println("hey");
         ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
         VisibilityChecker<?> checker = om.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker();
            om.setVisibilityChecker(checker.withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));

            try {
                System.out.println(om.writer().writeValueAsString(responseDTO));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

Libraries used: fasterXML - 2.5.0 version - jackson-core, jackson-data-bind and jackson-annotations

Comment: I think steps 3 and 4 are kind of obvious and it is not necessary to include them in the answer. I think it would be easier to understand without them.

Comment: Yeah its obvious. Just for completeness I have included it here.